# Reference the only pivot table on active worksheet

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I am calling a procedure from a number of worksheets that sets the print area to a pivot table's address.

```
With ActiveSheet

    .PageSetup.PrintArea = .PivotTables("Pivot_Table_Name_1").TableRange1.Address

End With

ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintPreview
```

There will only ever be one pivot table on the active worksheet. I am wondering if there is a way to reference 'the only pivot table on the worksheet' to avoid referencing the name of every pivot table individually (there are many).

Thank you.

Comment: `.PivotTables(1).TableRange1.Address`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the PivotTable by it's index in the Worksheet's PivotTable collection.

Here are two ways to iterate over the worksheets>

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
```

### Using an array yo limit which worksheets to iterate over

```
For Each ws In Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2"))
    With ws
        .PageSetup.PrintArea = .PivotTables(1).TableRange1.Address
    End With
Next
```

### Test to see if there are any PivotTables on the worksheet

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    With ws
        If .PivotTables.Count > 0 Then
            .PageSetup.PrintArea = .PivotTables(1).TableRange1.Address
        End If
    End With
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise there was a separate pivot table index for each sheet.

Comment: @MJV Thanks for accepting my answer.  I updated it because I accidentially used the `PivotTables` name instead of the index of the first `PivotTable`: `.PivotTables(1)` which was the whole point.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out from your first sentence and the comment on the OP ;)